# What does Magento 2 commands do?

Tags: dependency-injection, compilation, command, command-line-interface, magento2

I have been wondering about what exactly the following **Magento** command do.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Am I right, that it creates proxy classes? If yes, can someone give some more details of how **Magento** does this?

Answer (score 0):

when the s:d:c command is executed it tracks all xml files
(di.xml,config.xml,system,xml)
 and based on the rules of xml syntax it generates the **factory classes,intercepter classes,proxy classes, dependency of sequences etc .**
if you want to check how it is working than you should try to check out **magento-framework** module .
it is lengthy to explain that module here but follow this link you can get many details there.

[magento2 alan storm](https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/#magento-2-object-system)